# How can I get private key of trust wallet watch only

Tags: wallets, trust

Private and public key so I can be able to withdraw to my other wallet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

TrustWallet watch only addresses do not store the private key. It only stores the address.